# dynamic size array in linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

I want to have a linked list, with a variable which has dynamic size, 
because I want to just allocate different sizes for a variable in different nodes. 
for example node1 has a array variable with size 1, but node 2 has a array variable with size 10, and node3 never allocates this array. 
like this:

```
struct st{
   int * var_dynamic;
   int x;
};
```

now I want to initialize them. for the static one, it is like this:

```
struct st st1;
st1.x=1;
```

but how can I initialize the dynamic one?
Is it something like this?

```
st1.var_dynamic= new int [100];
```

and if yes, Is this way correct and efficient?

Comment: `st1.array[1]=1;` You didn't mention an `array` variable. Also, have you heard of `std::vector`?

Comment: Why not using a `std::vector`? It was designed to be efficient and error free.

Comment: Do you want to use a list in C++? If so, you'd just use `std::list`. Or you want an array? Then you want `std::vector`. Or do you want to implement a data structure yourself?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes your right, I correct it

Comment: @FrerichRaabe no I want to use it, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic, straightforward, and safe solution is to simply use `std::vector`:

```
struct st
{
  std::vector<int> var_dynamic;
  int x;
};
```

For using `std::vector`, consult a [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or your favourite [book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: @FattanehTalebi I suggest you first consult the docs I linked to, or pick up an introductory/reference book from those I linked to. Then, if there's still stomething unclear, search SO and the Internet, and if it's still unclear, ask another question.